# Sinatra application fails miserably in production/test environments when using session

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra, runtime-error, rack

I'm trying to run my Ruby Sinatra application in test and production. Here is the main class:

```
class Main < Sinatra::Application

  helpers Sinatra::ContentFor
  helpers Sinatra::Partials
  helpers Sinatra::Auth

  use Rack::Session::Cookie, :secret => 'supersecret' , :expire_after => 360000

  set :environment, :production

  configure :development do
    enable :sessions, :logging, :dump_errors, :inline_templates
    enable :methodoverride
    set :root, $_APP_PATH
    set :static, true
    logger = Logger.new($stdout)
  end

  configure :production do
    enable :logging, :dump_errors, :inline_templates
    enable :methodoverride
    set :root, $_APP_PATH
    set :static, true
    logger = Logger.new($stdout)
  end

  get "/2configure" do
    haml :'2configure'
  end

end
```

This works for `set :environment, :development`, but in "test" and "production" it gives the following error:

```
!! Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method `bytesize' for nil:NilClass
```

This is the top part of the stack trace:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `bytesize' for nil:NilClass:
    /home/id833541/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/utils.rb:291:in `bytesize'
    /home/id833541/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/utils.rb:351:in `secure_compare'
    /home/id833541/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb:115:in `unpacked_cookie_data'
    /home/id833541/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb:105:in `extract_session_id'
    /home/id833541/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:43:in `load_session_id!'
    /home/id833541/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:32:in `[]'
    /home/id833541/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:252:in `current_session_id'
    /home/id833541/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:258:in `session_exists?'
    /home/id833541/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:104:in `exists?'
    /home/id833541/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:114:in `load_for_read!'
    /home/id833541/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/rack-1.3.10/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:59:in `[]'
```

I'm almost certain it's something to do with sessions. For some reason this is a pain in the rectum to get right in Sinatra. I had this problem before but then I got it working by using `enable :sessions`. Now even that doesn't work anymore.

I've confirmed that the error occurs when accessing the session. In a HAML file I have:

```
%p="Welcome #{session[:full_name]}"
```

Which is empty the first time. But should that give an error?

It happens for any request, even in requests where I don't try to access the `session` object, but then there is no stack trace.

I'm using the Thin web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's because you've got `use Rack::Session::Cookie` and `enable :sessions` too. Use one or the other (I don't know *why* both won't work, just that it's one or the other).

By the way, have you tried using https://rubygems.org/gems/encrypted_cookie instead of Cookie? It's more secure.

---

Quick addendum: I notice you're inheriting from `Sinatra::Application`. If you're going to inherit to make a modular app then:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class Main < Sinatra::Base
```

If you want to use it as a [classic application](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Sinatra%3a%3aBase%20-%20Middleware,%20Libraries,%20and%20Modular%20Apps) then it's just:

```
require 'sinatra'

# no `class` statement

get "/blah" do # etc
```

---

Further to the comments:

If you're using a rackup file and Rack middleware, then this is how I structure an app:

```
root_of_project/
  config.ru        # This is just to start up the app via `rackup`.
  app/             # This will be the `root` setting in Sinatra
    config.rb      # This is where the logic of the Rack app lives.
    main.rb        # This is where your main Sinatra app lives
    models/
    views/
      2configure.haml
    public/
```

#### config.ru

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup(:default) # and anything else you want added in

root = File.expand_path File.dirname(__FILE__)
require File.join( root , "./app/config.rb" )

map "/" do
  run MY_APP_NAMESPACE.app
end
```

#### app/config.rb

```
require_relative "./main.rb" # Sinatra app

module MY_APP_NAMESPACE

  require 'encrypted_cookie'
  # standard cookie settings
  COOKIE_SETTINGS = {
    :path => "/",
    :expire_after => 86400, # In seconds, 1 day
    :secret => ENV["COOKIE_KEY"],  # I load this into the server's environment.
    :httponly => true
  }

  # This gets called in the config.ru. Doing it this way
  # makes it easy to include in specs.
  def self.app
    Rack::Builder.app do
      logger = Logger.new($stdout)


      cookie_settings = COOKIE_SETTINGS
      # more security if in production
      cookie_settings.merge!( :secure => true ) if ENV["RACK_ENV"] == "production"

      # AES encryption of cookies
      use Rack::Session::EncryptedCookie, cookie_settings

      # any other Rack middleware I put here.

      run Main
    end
  end
end # module
```

#### app/main.rb

```
require 'sinatra/base'

module MY_APP_NAMESPACE
  class Main < Sinatra::Base

    helpers Sinatra::ContentFor
    helpers Sinatra::Partials
    helpers Sinatra::Auth

    # no need for this here
    # use Rack::Session::Cookie, :secret => 'supersecret' , :expire_after => 360000

    # no need for this
    # set :environment, :production

    configure :development do
      #enable :sessions,  # no need
      enable :logging, :dump_errors, :inline_templates
      enable :methodoverride
      # Sinatra will work this out
      # set :root, $_APP_PATH
      # set :static, true # no need if you have a public directory
    end

    configure :production do
      enable :dump_errors, :inline_templates
      enable :methodoverride
      # set :root, $_APP_PATH
      # set :static, true  
      # logger = Logger.new($stdout) # no need for this, as far as I remember
      # see http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Logging
    end

    get "/2configure" do
      haml :'2configure'
    end

  end
```

Hopefully that will give you some ideas to try.

Comment: While I'm giving out gem recommendations :) I'm the maintainer of [Sinatra::Partial](https://rubygems.org/gems/sinatra-partial), which may be of use too.

Comment: I'm not using `enable :sessions` and `use ...` at the same time. Also indeed it appears this main class isn't necessary. Will it lead to errors?

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester I was referring to the one in your `:development` config. I think that, and the inherit from Sinatra::Application will lead to strange errors _even_ if it appears that you've specified it only for one environment. Have you tried without `enable :sessions` specified anywhere?

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't work. Also I've tried to run the application by not using a `Main` class but that doesn't work. I'm using Thin web server. In the `config.ru` file I have `map "/" do run Main end` which is necessary to run the application. I don't know what to replace that with to make it work...

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester I've updated the answer with how I structure my apps and a few comments. Hopefully that will give you something to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the problem is within `Rack::Session::Cookie` somewhere.
I can use the following instead for now:

```
use Rack::Session::Pool, :secret => 'super secret' , :expire_after => 360000
```

But my application is later to be integrated with another one where `Rack::Session::Cookie` is currently used.

I would still like to know why `Cookie` doesn't work.